# Moving last section of list two to the left

Tags: python, python-3.x

short question about moving the last item of a list inside a nested list two to the left for example:

```
list = [['Swimming', 'Jason', 'jsmg1', '2', '1352452'], 
       ['Football', 'Chris', 'cfb1', '1', '1352527'],
       ['Tennis', 'J', 'Paul', 'pten1', '2', '1132624']]
```

to

```
list = [['Swimming', 'Jason', '1352452', 'jsmg1, '2'], 
       ['Football', 'Chris', '1352527', 'cfb1', '1'],
       ['Tennis', 'J', 'Paul', '1132624', 'pten1', '2']]
```

how can this be done?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use slice assignment.

```
l = [['Swimming', 'Jason', 'jsmg1', '2', '1352452'], 
       ['Football', 'Chris', 'cfb1', '1', '1352527'],
       ['Tennis', 'J', 'Paul', 'pten1', '2', '1132624']]

for row in l:
    row[2:] = row[4], row[2], row[3]
```

The result:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(l)
[['Swimming', 'Jason', '1352452', 'jsmg1', '2'],
 ['Football', 'Chris', '1352527', 'cfb1', '1'],
 ['Tennis', 'J', '2', 'Paul', 'pten1']]
```

Comment: Or for moving last element of arbitrary length >= 3 list two to the left without assuming it's exactly five elements each, `row[-3:] = row[-1], row[-3], row[-2]` (might be worth making `swapper = operator.itemgetter(-1, -3, -2)` so you can just do `row[-3:] = swapper(row)`).